# Default field separator for awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk, posix, separator

Is the default separator only space for awk?

Comment: The default field delimiter or field separator (FS) is `[ \t]+`, i.e. one or more space and tab characters.

Comment: @Thor no, it's not. See the man page.

Comment: @EdMorton: Right, I missed newlines, i.e. `FS='[ \t\n]+`.  But this only has an effect when RS does not include newlines.

Comment: @Thor not exactly since even if you have an `RS` that includes newlines the default `FS` will have an effect if you construct a string containing newlines and you do `split(string,arr)`.

Comment: Good question, not stupid at all

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's a **pragmatic summary** that applies to **all major Awk implementations**:

- *GNU* Awk (`gawk`) - the default `awk` in *some* Linux distros
- *Mawk* (`mawk`) - the default `awk` in *some* Linux distros (e.g., earlier versions of Ubuntu <sup>[crysman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878211/crysman) reports that version 19.04 now comes with *GNU* Awk - see his comment below.</sup>)
- *BWK* Awk - the default `awk` on BSD-like platforms, including macOS

<sup>On Linux, `awk -W version` will tell you which implementation the default `awk` is.

BWK Awk *only* understands `awk --version` (which GNU Awk understands *in addition* to `awk -W version`).</sup>

**Recent versions of *all* these implementations follow the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) with respect to *field* separators**<sup>[1]</sup> (but not *record* separators).

Glossary:

- **`RS`** is the **input-*record* separator**, which describes **how the input is broken into *records***:

  - The **POSIX-mandated default value** is a **newline**, also referred to as `\n` below; that is, **input is broken into *lines* by default**.
  - On `awk`'s command line, `RS` can be specified as `-v RS=<sep>`.
  - POSIX restricts `RS` to a *literal, single-character* value, but GNU Awk and Mawk support *multi-character* values that may be *extended regular expressions* (BWK Awk does *not* support that).
- **`FS`** is the **input-*field* separator**, which describes how ***each record* is split into *fields***; it may be an *extended regular expression*.

  - On `awk`'s command line, `FS` can be specified as `-F <sep>` (or `-v FS=<sep>`).
  - **The [POSIX-mandated default value](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) is *formally* a *space* (`0x20`), but that space is not *literally* interpreted as the (only) separator, but has *special meaning***; see below.

---

**By default**:

- **any run** of **spaces** *and/or* **tabs** and/or **newlines** is treated as a **field separator**
- with **leading and trailing runs ignored**.

<sup>The POSIX spec. [uses the abstraction `<blank>` for spaces and tabs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_04_01), which is true for *all* locales, but *could* comprise *additional* characters in specific locales - I don't know if any such locales exist.</sup>

Note that **with the default input-record separator** (`RS`), `\n`, **newlines *typically* do not enter the picture as field separators**, because **no record *itself*  contains `\n`** in that case.

**Newlines as field separators *do* come into play**, however:

- When **`RS` is set to a value that results in records *themselves* containing `\n` instances** (such as when `RS` is set to the *empty string*; see below).
- ***Generally*, when the `split()` function is used to split a string into array elements without an explicit-field separator argument.**

  - Even though the *input records* won't contain `\n` instances in case the default `RS` is in effect, the `split()` function when invoked without an explicit field-separator argument on a *multi-line string from a different source* (e.g., a variable passed via the `-v` option or as a pseudo-filename) *always* treats `\n` as a field separator.

---

**Important NON-default considerations**:

- **Assigning the *empty* string to `RS` has special meaning**: it reads the input in ***paragraph mode***, meaning that the input is broken into records by **runs of *non-empty lines***, with **leading and trailing runs of empty lines ignored**.
- When you **assign anything *other* than a *literal* space to `FS`**, the **interpretation of `FS` *changes fundamentally***:

  - **A *single* character or each character from a specified character *set*** is **recognized *individually* as a field separator** - not *runs* of it, as with the default.

    - For instance, setting `FS` to `[ ]` - even though it *effectively* amounts to a single space - causes every *individual* space instance in each record to be treated as a field separator.
    - To recognize *runs*, the regex quantifier (duplication symbol) `+` must be used; e.g., `[\t]+` would recognize *runs* of tabs as a single separator.
  - ***Leading and trailing* separators are NOT ignored**, and, instead, separate *empty* fields.
  - **Setting `FS` to the *empty string*** means that **each *character*** of a record is **its own field**.
- As [mandated by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), if **`RS` is set to the *empty string*** (paragraph mode), ***newlines* (`\n`) are *also* considered field separators**, irrespective of the value of `FS`.

---

<sup>[1] Unfortunately, GNU Awk up to at least version 4.1.3 complies with an *obsolete* POSIX standard with respect to field separators when you use the option to enforce POSIX compliance, `-P` (`--posix`): with that option in effect and `RS` set to a *non-empty* value, newlines (`\n` instances) are NOT recognized as field separators. The GNU Awk manual spells out the obsolete behavior (but neglects to mention that it doesn't apply when `RS` is set to the *empty* string). The POSIX standard changed in 2008 (see comments) to *also* consider *newlines* field separators when `FS` has its default value - as GNU Awk has always done *without* `-P` (`--posix`).

Here are 2 commands that verify the behavior described above:</sup>

- With `-P` in effect and `RS` set to the *empty string*, `\n` is *still* treated as a field separator:
  `gawk -P -F' ' -v RS='' '{ printf "<%s>, <%s>\n", $1, $2 }' <<< $'a\nb'`
- With `-P` in effect and a *non-empty* `RS`, `\n` is NOT treated as a field separator - this is the obsolete behavior:
  `gawk -P -F' ' -v RS='|' '{ printf "<%s>, <%s>\n", $1, $2 }' <<< $'a\nb'`
  *A fix is coming*, according to the GNU Awk maintainers; expect it in version *4.2* (no time frame given).
  (Tip of the hat to @JohnKugelman and @EdMorton for their help.)

Comment: Thanks mklement0, I read the reply from John as well and it seems only space is default delimiter? However you mentioned both space and Tab? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: In short: While a space is _formally_ the default `FS` value, it _stands for_ space, tabs, and newlines. I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: The POSIX standard changed and gawk is supporting the older version. See the 2004 standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) which states `a field is a string of non- <blank>s` vs the 2013 standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) which states `a field is a string of non- <blank> non- <newline> characters`. You should email bug-gawk@gnu.org about that.

Comment: @EdMorton: Turns out I misread the POSIX spec and you were correct: the spec did change as you describe in POSIX.1-2008 (SUS v4). Per your suggestion (thanks) I've emailed bug-gawk@gnu.org and have since heard back that a fix is coming in the "next major release", but I'm unclear on what version that is.

Comment: @mklement0 it seems Ubuntu 19.04 comes with both gawk and mawk, here is where you find it: http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.04/ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.manifest . BUT, indeed, gawk is default: `❱ which -a "awk"
/usr/bin/awk
❱ file /usr/bin/awk
/usr/bin/awk: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/awk
❱ file /etc/alternatives/awk
/etc/alternatives/awk: symbolic link to /usr/bin/gawk`

Comment: Thanks, @crysman - I've updated the answer to point to your comment.

Answer (score 12):

The question `the default delimiter is only space for awk?` is ambiguous but I'll try to answer both of the questions you might be asking.

The default value of the `FS` variable (which holds the field separator that tells awk how to separate records into fields as it reads them) is a single space character.

The thing that awk uses to separate records into fields is a "field separator" which is a regular expression with some additional functionality that only applies when the field separator is a single blank character. That additional functionality is that:

1. Leading and trailing white space is ignored during field splitting.
2. Fields are separated at chains of contiguous space characters which includes blanks, tabs and newlines.
3. If you want to use a literal blank character as a field separator you must specify it as `[ ]` instead of just a standalone literal blank char like you could in a regexp.

In addition to field separators being used to split records into fields as the input is read they are used in some other contexts, e.g. the 3rd arg for `split()`, so it's important for you to know which contexts require a string or a regexp or a fieldsep and the man page clearly specifies each.

Among other things, the above explains this:

```
$ echo ' a b c ' | awk '{printf "%d: <%s> <%s> <%s>\n", NF, $1, $2, $3}'
3: <a> <b> <c>
$ echo ' a b c ' | awk -F' ' '{printf "%d: <%s> <%s> <%s>\n", NF, $1, $2, $3}'
3: <a> <b> <c>
$ echo ' a b c ' | awk -F'[ ]' '{printf "%d: <%s> <%s> <%s>\n", NF, $1, $2, $3}'                              
5: <> <a> <b>
```

so if you don't understand why the first 2 produce the same output but the last is different, please ask.

Comment: Please don't confuse "blank" with "space". "space" is the actual space character (`0x20`), whereas "blank" is a [potentially locale-specific _abstraction_](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_04_01): "In the POSIX locale, only the <space> and <tab> shall be included. In a locale definition file, the <space> and <tab> are automatically included in this class." (I can see no umbrella term in the POSIX spec that covers both "blank" and newlines.)

Comment: Otherwise, a great answer.

Answer (score 8):

Let's take a look at the GNU awk man page:

> `FS` —         The input field separator, a space by default.  See *Fields*, above.

To the *Fields* section!

> As each input record is read, gawk splits the record into fields, using the value of the `FS` variable as the field  separator.   If `FS`  is  a  single  character,  fields  are  separated by that character.  If `FS` is the null string, then each individual character becomes a separate field.  Otherwise, `FS` is expected to be a full regular expression.  In the special case that  `FS`  is  a  single space,  **fields  are  separated  by  runs of spaces and/or tabs and/or newlines.**

Comment: Hi John, a bit lost in your reply. Does it mean only space, or both space/Tab are used as default delimiter?

Comment: Just to complement this answer: Even though the quotes are from the GNU Awk manual page, they also apply to the other Awk implementation that some Linux distros come with by default, Mawk (`mawk`; e.g., on Ubuntu) - and they also apply to BWK Awk, as found on BSD-like platforms, including macOS.

Comment: @mklement0 : @mklement0 : diff note : now ghetto `BWK awk` can also handle regex in `RS` : `jot -s '' -c - 33 126 | gtr -d '\n' |  nawk '$-_ =NR "=NR:{ "($-_)" }:NF=" NF' RS='(:|[0-9]|\42)+' 
1=NR:{ ! }:NF=1
2=NR:{ #$%&'()*+,-./ }:NF=1
3=NR:{ ;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_\`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ }:NF=1`

Answer (score 2):

'[ ]+' works for me.
Run `awk -W version` to get the awk version. Mine is `GNU Awk 4.0.2`.

```
# cat a.txt
tcp        0      0 10.192.25.199:65002     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:26895         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18422           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.192.25.199:8888      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.192.25.199:8093      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8670            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

For example, I want to get the Listen port.  So I need to use the awk default delimiter added with ':'

```
# cat a.txt  | awk -F '[ ]+|:' '{print $5}'
65002
26895
111
18422
22
8888
50010
50075
8093
8670
```

If you just want to test the default delimiter, you can run

```
# cat a.txt  | awk -F '[ ]+' '{print $4}'
10.192.25.199:65002
127.0.0.1:26895
0.0.0.0:111
0.0.0.0:18422
0.0.0.0:22
10.192.25.199:8888
0.0.0.0:50010
0.0.0.0:50075
10.192.25.199:8093
0.0.0.0:8670
```

The result is as expected.