# Why is awk saying that strings representing identical IP address are unequal?

Tags: string, awk, equality

Here is the sample output:

```
   $echo "0.0.0.0 : 0.0.0.0" | awk -F':' '{print $1==$2}' 
0
```

Why are the strings not equal? What do I need to do to make awk think

Comment: @Thomas: No - since I did not put that in the echo command.

Comment: I guess I need echo "0.0.0.0 : 0.0.0.0" | awk -F' : ' '{print $1==$2}' 
1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you are using `:` as the delimiter. `$1` will contain `0.0.0.0<space>` and `$2` will contain `<space>0.0.0.0`

You can specify a sequence of characters as delimiter:

```
... | awk -F' : ' '{print $1==$2}'
```

The above command is using the sequence: *space* *colon* *space* as delimiter.

Comment: Good one! You can also leave the FS as is and check 1st and 3rd fields: `awk '{print $1==$3}' `.

Comment: @fedorqui You are right! Doing so would be much simpler! (facepalm! :)

Comment: Actually, `-F' : '` is not a regex, but a literal string. For what it's worth, the solution is not portable, because `-F` does not accept regex, but happens to work for the given input (see POSIX description of [awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)).

Comment: @ThomasDickey You are right, only `gawk` supports a regex as delimiter. While fixed patterns are a subset of a regexes (I had gawk in mind), I admit that *regex* was not the quite right term. Good catch! Changed that.

Comment: Actually, [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html) does this as well.  I do not recall if BWK does.  See also [default field separator for awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405694/default-field-separator-for-awk)