# Cut a specific group of characters from an array

Tags: android, unix, awk, adb, cut

I am trying to get the elapsedCpu time for a certain process using adb commands.
I am using this command in order to get some info about the com.example.android process

```
adb shell cat /proc/1234/stat
```

(1234 is the PID of com.example.android)

The output result looks like this:

```
24334 (gdev.loadtester) S 490 490 0 0 -1 6545623 65464564 0 1 0 888 999 0 0 20 549351656579 549351656579 549351657438 0
```

I am only interested in the 14th group of numbers, that being 888. How do i trim this output in order to extract only this number, so that I have 888 as a result of the command. Each group of chars will always be separated by a space.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{print $14}' file
```

Explained some: By default awk uses spaces as *input field separator* `FS` (well..., see, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30406868/4162356)). `print $14` outputs the 14th `FS` separated field of each record.

Comment: It's customary to comment when down voting.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

```
adb shell cat /proc/1234/stat "| cut -d ' ' -f 14"
```

Comment: That'll work just fine.