# How can I keep the leading white spaces while removing last field in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to create a template of a config file containing credentials dynamically. The copy should keep the structure but with the values replaced by empty strings (i.e. ""). I use `awk` for this purpose.

```sh
awk -v dq="\"" '{ if($NF ~ /^[&|\*|\n]/ || $1 == $NF) print $0; else {$NF=""; print $0 dq dq;} }' .config.yaml >> .config_temp.yaml
```

The problem is in the else statement. When I set `$NF=""` the leading white space are not printed anymore. If I do not set the last field to an empty string, I do not observe this behavior but obviously do not receive the intended output (see below).

How can I set the last field as an empty string while keeping the leading white spaces?

I don't want to manually add a number of white spaces since the intent varies.

**config.yaml** (Input)

```
DEVELOPMENT: &development
  <<: *common

  check_access_token: False

  database:
    mongodb:
      database: test
      hostname: localhost
      port: 27017
      username: ""
      password: ""

      collection:
        col_1: test_1
        col_2: test_2
        col_3: test_3
        col_4: test_4
```

**conf_temp.yaml** (actual output)

```
DEVELOPMENT: &development
  <<: *common

check_access_token: ""

  database:
    mongodb:
database: ""
hostname: ""
port: ""
username: ""
password: ""

      collection:
property: ""
ctrl_voc: ""
form: ""
user: ""
```

**Expected output**

```
DEVELOPMENT: &development
  <<: *common

check_access_token: ""

  database:
    mongodb:
      database: ""
      hostname: ""
      port: ""
      username: ""
      password: ""

      collection:
        property: ""
        ctrl_voc: ""
        form: ""
        user: ""
```

## Edit (after Sundeep's replay)

Thank you for your answer. It almost works as I expect. However, I do not receive the same output as you. If I call

```sh
 awk -F'[ ]' -v dq="\"" 'NF>1 && $NF !~ /^[*&]|:$/{$NF = dq dq} 1' .conf.yaml
```

I receive the following output:

```sh
DEVELOPMENT: &development
  <<: *common

  check_access_token: ""

  ""                             <--
    ""                           <--
      database: ""
      hostname: ""
      port: ""
      username: ""
      password: ""

      ""                         <--
        property: ""
        ctrl_voc: ""
        form: ""
        user: ""
```

The indention is as expected but the keys of the upper levels are replaced by quotes (see arrows).

I receive the same output, if I use your second suggestion with `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Default field separator for awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405694/default-field-separator-for-awk) to understand what happens when `FS` has default value or set to single space character.

You can avoid it by using some other means to convey single space, like `[ ]`

```
$ awk -F'[ ]' -v dq="\"" 'NF>1 && $NF !~ /^[*&]|:$/{$NF = dq dq} 1' ip.txt
DEVELOPMENT: &development
  <<: *common

  check_access_token: ""

  database:
    mongodb:
      database: ""
      hostname: ""
      port: ""
      username: ""
      password: ""

      collection:
        col_1: ""
        col_2: ""
        col_3: ""
        col_4: ""
```

- `NF>1` to avoid changing empty lines
- `$NF !~ /^[*&]|:$/` check if last field doesn't start with `*` or `&` or doesn't end with `:`
- if both the above conditions are satisfied, set last field to `""`
- `1` is idiomatic way to print contents of `$0`

For the given sample, you can also use:

```
sed '/:$/! s/ [^*&][^ ]*$/ ""/' ip.txt
```

Comment: I do not receive the same output as you. See the extension of my question.

Comment: perhaps you have dos style line endings? what is the output you get for `file .config.yaml`? if it is dos ending, then using `:\r$` instead of `:$` would help.. see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:** How can I update a field without changing the original field-separators.

According to the awk POSIX standard, when you update a field using `$i = expr` it causes the value of $0 to be recomputed, with the fields being separated by the value of `OFS`.

For any field separator which is **not an ere**, the solution is simple. Changing field `n` is done as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="string"}
     {$n="new_value"}
     { ... }' file
```

For other field-separators, this is a bit more problematic:

- If `FS=" "` (default value), any spacing before and after the record are ignored, any combination of tabs and fields are used
- If `FS="ere"` an Extended regular expression, you do not really know what the field separator is going to be. If `FS="fo*`, it can be anything from `f` to `fooooooo`.

In POSIX awk, you need to do do some nasty manipulations:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="ere"}
     # split original record
     { split($0,a,FS) }
     # update field value
     { a[n]="new_value" }
     # rebuild record
     {
       match($0,$1); rec=substr($0,1,RSTART-1); t=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
       for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {
          match(t,$(i+1)); rec = rec a[i] substr(t,1,RSTART-1)
          t=substr(t,RSTART+RLENGTH)
       }
       $0 = rec a[NF] t
     }
     { ... }' file
```

In GNU awk, you can make use of `split` in a bit more generic way as it has an extension to save the original separators:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="ere"}
     # split original record
     { split($0,a,FS,f) }
     # update field value
     { a[n]="new_value" }
     # rebuild record
     { rec=f[0]; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) rec=rec a[i] f[i]; $0 = rec }
     { ... }' file
```

**General comment:** GNU awk could really benefit from a routine that reverses the `split` command and does a `combine`