# awk command to print columns with colum data

Tags: awk

`cat file1.txt | awk -F '{print $1 "|~|" $2 "|~|" $3}' > file2.txt`

I am using above command to filter first three columns from file1 and put into file.

But only getting the column names and not the column data.

How to do that?

`|~|` - is the delimiter.

**file1.txt** has values as :

```
 a|~|b|~|c|~|d|~|e
 1|~|2|~|3|~|4|~|5
 11|~|22|~|33|~|44|~|55
 111|~|222|~|333|~|444|~|555
```

my expedted output is :

```
 a|~|b|~|c
 1|~|2|~|3
 11|~|22|~|33
 111|~|222|~|333
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. You need to set field separator to `|~|` and remove starting space from lines, then print the lines.

```
awk -F'\\|~\\|' -v OFS='|~|' '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"");print $1,$2,$3}' Input_file
```

In case you want to keep spaces(which was in initial post before edit) then try following:

```
awk -F'\\|~\\|' -v OFS='|~|' '{print $1,$2,$3}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Had a chat with user in room and got to know why this code was not working for user because of `gunzip -c file` was being used wrongly, its output was being saved into a variable on which user was running `awk` program, so correcting that command generated right file and `awk` program ran fine on it. Adding this as a reference for future readers.

Comment: Yep, you got it! I hate the `"|~|"` ones -- whoever thought that up as a field separator -- should be shot...

Comment: But I am only getting the column names, I want the column data as well.

Comment: @Aviator, With your shown samples this code works. Is your actual file is same as shown samples?

Comment: Its not the same file, but its in the same format!

Comment: @Aviator, yeah, if its same format it should work IMHO. What is not working could you please elaborate on this one?

Comment: What is not working ? -- Only the column names getting printed. that means i am getting only : a|~|b|~|c

Comment: But I want the column data also.

Comment: @Aviator, with your shown samples it gives columns data. Post here 1 line of sample input and expected output to make it clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234970/discussion-between-aviator-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @Aviator, Hi, could you please update your question(by not changing it drastically) where you could mention 2 points,1- I believe you needed to remove starting tabs/spaces in each line(which is lost in question's editing), 2- your gunzip issue by which is your file is getting generated. if you edit your question this will make it different from your previous question(which this question actually is), else this may get close as duplicate. Kindly do make changes to this question, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @Aviator, Hi, could you please update your question(by not changing it drastically) where you could mention 2 points,1- I believe you needed to remove starting tabs/spaces in each line(which is lost in question's editing), 2- your gunzip issue by which is your file is getting generated. if you edit your question this will make it different from your previous question(which this question actually is), else this may get close as duplicate. Kindly do make changes to this question, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be:

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="|~|" '{gsub(/[|][~][|]/,","); sub(/^\s*/,"");  print $1,$2,$3}' file1.txt
```

The approach simply replaces all `"|~|"` with a `","` setting the output file separator to `"|~|"`. All leading whitespace is trimmed with `sub()`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file1.txt`, you would have:

```
$ awk -v FS="," -v OFS="|~|" '{gsub(/[|][~][|]/,","); sub(/^\s*/,"");  print $1,$2,$3}' file1.txt
a|~|b|~|c
1|~|2|~|3
11|~|22|~|33
111|~|222|~|333
```

Let me know if this is what you intended. You can simply redirect, e.g. `> file2.txt` to write to the second file.

Answer (score 2):

For such cases, my `bash+awk` script [rcut](https://github.com/learnbyexample/regexp-cut) comes in handy:

```sh
rcut -Fd'|~|' -f-3 ip.txt
```

The `-F` option enables fixed string input delimiter (which is given using the `-d` option). And by default, the output field separator will also be same as `-d` when `-F` is active. `-f-3` is similar to `cut` syntax to specify first three fields.

---

For better speed, use [hck](https://github.com/sstadick/hck) command:

```sh
hck -Ld'|~|' -D'|~|' -f-3 ip.txt
```

Here, `-L` enables literal field separator and `-D` specifies output field separator.

Another benefit is that `hck` supports `-z` option to automatically handle common compressed formats based on filename extension (adding this since OP had an issue with compressed input).

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
sed 's/|~|/\t/g' file1.txt | awk '{print $1"|~|"$2"|~|"$3}' > file2.txt
```

First replace the `|~|` delimiter, and use the default `awk` separator, then `print` columns what you need.

Comment: yes, I delete that flag, and if first use `sed` to replace some character, it will cover the space case auto by `awk` I think.

Comment: But this is only returning the column names i want the column data as well.

Comment: @Aviator could you show your running screenshot? It works for me, this command will return the all rows with define columns.

Comment: how can I put screenshot(image) here ?

Comment: You could update your question, but suggest paste it to comment me.

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk and that would fail if any of the fields in the input contained blanks or tabs.

Comment: Thanks point that, but I have test that and it works, the default `awk` separator will handle the blanks or tabs. Check it from "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405694/default-field-separator-for-awk".