# awk -F with regex has a strange behavior

Tags: linux, awk

I use the following command to get local ips (Ubuntu 22.04):

`ifconfig|grep broadcast|awk '{print $2}'`

But if I use `-F "[ ]+"` option:

`ifconfig|grep broadcast|awk -F "[ ]+" '{print $3}'`

To get local ips I **must** use $3 instead of $2. why?

**I think the right behavior is：**
No matter whether we use `-F "[ ]+"` option or not, the result is the same: $2 is the IP address.

PS: The awk in macOS is working well.

```bash
ifconfig|grep broadcast|awk '{print $2}' # for macOS
ifconfig|grep broadcast|awk '{print $2}' # for Linux
ifconfig|grep broadcast|awk -F "[: ]+" '{print $2}' # for macOS
ifconfig|grep broadcast|awk -F "[: ]+" '{print $3}' # for Linux, Why use $3?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default field separator for awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405694/default-field-separator-for-awk) "By default any run of spaces and/or tabs and/or newlines is treated as a field separator with leading and trailing runs ignored"